# Spring boot embedded jettty thread pool maximum size

Tags: spring-boot

I want to configure Thread pool size for my application which is using spring boot embedded jetty server. Below is the code snippet i am using.

I want to know what is the maximum thread pool size I can set for the embedded jetty server and is it the correct way of configuring it?

```
@Bean
   public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory jettyConfigBean() {
      JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jef = new JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
      jef.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

         public void customize(org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server) {
            final QueuedThreadPool threadPool = server.getBean(QueuedThreadPool.class);
            server.setHandler(handlers);
         }
      });
      return jef;
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Speaking for spring-boot 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT:

This is for jetty and tomcat and undertow configurable via

```
server.jetty.acceptors
server.tomcat.max-connections
server.undertow.io-threads
```

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties for a complete reference.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of threads you can set is dependent on your machine, not so much on the hosting software. If you have a monster machine you can probably have hundreds of threads, whereas a regular laptop would probably only be able to handle tens of threads. You need to tune your configuration by testing. A good way is to setup a load test, for example see if 50 threads with 50 req/sec will crash your service, then check if increasing/decreasing the number of threads will help. You can find the limits of your application and machine with such a technique.

Regarding the correctness of the configuration, you can read this blog post which explains it very well: http://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2014/10/07/spring_boot_jetty_thread_pool.html

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

While working on newer versions, you need to create a server factory bean in a configuration file. I tested this on Spring Boot version 2.1.6 while the document I referred to is for version 2.3.3

```
    @Bean
    public ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
        JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.setPort(8080);
        factory.setContextPath("/my-app");
        QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
        threadPool.setMinThreads(10);
        threadPool.setMaxThreads(100);
        threadPool.setIdleTimeout(60000);
        factory.setThreadPool(threadPool);
        return factory;
    }
```

Following is the link to Spring Docs: [customizing-embedded-containers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-customizing-embedded-containers)